# Как нажать в webBrowser на кнопку?

Tags: c#

Есть такой html код -

`<button class="flat_button profile_btn_cut_left">Отправить сообщение</button>`,

как программно нажать на кнопку через webBrowser?(кнопка "отправить сообщение" в вконтакте)

делаю так, но не получается

```
foreach (HtmlElement he in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
            {
                if (he.GetAttribute("class").Equals("flat_button profile_btn_cut_left"))
                {
                    he.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Можно же сразу по классу выбирать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
HTMLInputElementClass iElement = (HTMLInputElementClass)he.DomElement;
iElement.click();
```

- [Submission of a webpage form using WebBrowser control in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902006/submission-of-a-webpage-form-using-webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp)
- [Cannot cast HTMLInputElementClass to HTMLButtonElementClass with IE automation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037764/cannot-cast-htmlinputelementclass-to-htmlbuttonelementclass-with-ie-automation)

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно, только нужно поменять `GetAttribute("class")` на `GetAttribute("className")`